# Implicit conversion with more than one parameter, and operator overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion

I am currently reading "The C++ Programming Language" book. Below is the relevant code

```
class complex {
public:
  complex(double r, double i): re{r}, im{i} {}
  complex(double r): complex{r,0} {}
  complex(): complex{0,0} {}

  complex& operator-=(complex z) {
    this->re -= z.re;
    this->im -= z.im;
    return *this;
  } 
private:
  double re,im;
};

inline complex operator-(complex a, complex b) {
  return a -= b;
}

inline complex operator-(complex z) {
  return{ 0, 0 } - z;
}
```

The unary `operator-` gives an error -

> syntax error : missing ';' before '-'

However, both of the following variants are considered correct by the compiler

```
inline complex operator-(complex z) {
  return 0 - z;
}
```

and

```
inline complex operator-(complex z) {
  return {-z.real(), -z.imag()};
}
```

I think that implicit conversion in happening in both these cases.
Then why is

```
inline complex operator-(complex z) {
  return {0,0} - z;
}
```

flagged as an error?

EDIT - Fixing return type of operator-= function call, and adding operator-(), as it it relevant to the question.

Comment: Which compiler (version) ?

Comment: The grammar doesn't allow a braced initializer list to be an operand of most operators, including `-`.

Comment: @Ajay, it's visual studio 2013

Comment: @T.C., While braced initializer list can be used to construct an object, if all parameters are passed correctly, but it cannot be used as an operand for most operators. Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming the example in the textbook also provides a binary `operator-` because without that the code would fail to compile even if `{0, 0}` was implicitly converted to a `complex` on the offending line.

```
return{ 0, 0 } - z;
```

The reason this line won't compile is because a *braced-init-list* (`{0, 0}`) is not an expression, and as such does not have a type. So it cannot be used as one of the operands to binary `operator-`.

The reason `return {-z.real(), -z.imag()};` works is because it's explicitly allowed by the standard.

*§6.6.3/2 [stmt.return]*

> **The *expression* or *braced-init-list* of a return statement is called its operand**. ... A return statement with any other operand shall be used only in a function whose return type is not *cv* `void`; **the return statement initializes the object or reference to be returned by copy-initialization** (8.5) **from the operand**.

The *copy-initialization* in this case is *copy-list-initialization* (*§8.5.4 [dcl.init.list]*) and it'll consider the `complex(double r, double i)` constructor because it is not `explicit`.

---

The return type of `operator-=` is also strange, it modifies the `complex` instance, but then returns a copy. A typical implementation would be

```
complex& operator-=(complex const& z) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I have edited the question yo include operator-, and fixed return type. I understand that braced-init-list {0,0} is not and expression, but why is return {-z.real(), -z.imag()}; allowed, when it clearly being used to initialize a complex object?

Comment: @kaustubh The braced-init can appear single in a return statement, in which case it constructs a temporary of the return type, see #8 [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization).